# linux eclipse c++ local namespaces and "std::"

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I am trying my first c++ project and am starting small, I think.  I am using Eclipse Luna and am trying to take the defaults for build env everywhere that I can.  I suspect that the following is vary naive code but you gotta start somewhere.

I will eventually have 4 co/sub projects in this:

1. Commandline interface to a static lib
2. ".so" lib that will be dynamically loaded into a different, thied party app and uses the static lib
3. A static library, mentioned above, that does the back end work of the combined app.
4. A utility class (for now, maybe a small lib later) for utility classes and functions common to the other sub projects.

There are a ton of questions on best practices, namespaces, etc that I would like to ask but I'll keep this short.

I have the following c++ header file:

```
/*
 * Utilities.h
 *
 */

#ifndef UTILITIES_H_
#define UTILITIES_H_

// A

namespace UserTrackingUtilities {
// B
#include <string>
#include <exception>
    using namespace std;

    class MyException: public std::exception {
        public:
            MyException(std::string ss) : s(ss) {
            }
            ~MyException() throw () {
            } // Updated

            std::string s;

            const char* what() const throw () {
                return s.c_str();
            }
    };
}

#endif /* UTILITIES_H_ */
```

This is an exception utility (found in a different StackOverflow thread) that I am wrapping in a namespace of my own -- I think.

Eclipse is showing several issues with this header file.  I'll start with one: it doesn't like the `std::string` construct.  It doesn't matter if I put the `#include`s and/or the `using` statements at point `A` or `B`.

I've also tried this with the Linux GCC and ADT tool chains.

Pointers and advice welcome.

Comment: Don't put `#include` statements inside namespaces. Your code compiles fine for me when I move the `#includes` to point `A`.

Comment: And don't say `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Eclipse Luna and Mars with CDT eat that file fine even with the includes and `using namespace std;` at position B. Death to `using namspace std;`, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <exception>
```

Should be before

```
namespace UserTrackingUtilities {
```

**BTW:**

If you use `using namespace std`, you can write `string` instead of `std::string`.

But I suggest **not to use** `using namespace std` to avoid name conflicts and ambiguities.

**Update:**

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

namespace UserTrackingUtilities {

    class MyException: public std::exception {
        public:
            MyException(std::string ss) : s(ss) {
            }
            ~MyException() throw () {
            } // Updated

            std::string s;

            const char* what() const throw () {
                return s.c_str();
            }
    };
}

int main()
{
    UserTrackingUtilities::MyException ex("Hello World");
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes my brain hurt. I move the includes to point A and remove the std namespace using.  The `std::string s;` tells me `‘string’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type`

Comment: the line `return s.c_str();` tells me that s was not defined in this scope. I think my eclipse is hosed

Comment: @7Reeds If you get an compiler error, it is very very very very very very seldom the fault of the compiler or the IDE.

Comment: @7Reeds It sounds like your project is not configured correctly.

Comment: @7Reeds Seems like something is wrong with `#include <string>`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this asap.